# SQL Server Calling Stored Procedure from within Stored Procedure Select Query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Let's I have a stored procedure as follows :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[employeedetail]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ws.id as WorkflowStepId, 
    ws.workflow_id as WorkflowId,
    FROM [workflow_step] as ws 
    INNER JOIN [super_group] as sg on ws.workflow_id = sg.WORKFLOW_ID
    LEFT JOIN [alias] as alias on ws.id = alias.workflow_step_id
END
```

Which Would give me something like

100, 200

What I would like to do is run the first value against a stored procedure which will turn my ID into an address

so I would have like

My Address, 200

So I want to do something like

```
Select exec geo_sp_id_address_string(ws.id), ws.workflow_id......
```

But I can't get the syntax right, if any one has any ideas how I can get this working ?

Answer (score 0):

Use table variable

```
declare @MyTable table (id int, workflow_id int)

insert into @MyTable (id, workflow_id)
exec tmp.employeedetail

select geo_sp_id_address_string(id), workflow_id
from @MyTable
```